# Jmeter- charts appear empty after generate html report

Tags: jmeter

Please I am trying to generate html report for performance test through jmetet and After generate html report
When All results pass below happen :
some charts (response time charts , latencies ) appear empty
Noting that when there us some failer requests charts appear but with response time of failer request only !!

I try to open user properties also jmeter properties and all setting is normal

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have customizations in [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) and/or [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Let's start clean:

1. Install [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
2. Run example test plan and generate dashboard as follows:

   ```
   ./jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000 -n -t ../extras/Test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
   ```

   You should see charts

   [image]

Then you can cross-check the default configuration in *jmeter.properties* and *user.properties* files and either use that "clean" JMeter for your testing or identify the properties which cause the behaviour you're experiencing.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I am using  V 5.4.1 my main problem is charts appear only when there is failer requests and if there is both (failer , pass) reqiests ,   pass time or requests dont appear in charts ,  i review user proporities and i only put in it granularity configuration ..